# Redshift AES Decrypt UDF

Tags: python, aes, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions, skein

I need to load some encrypted data into AWS Redshift table (well, a few fields with encrypted data) and already have a Java Decrypt function that I'll need to port to Python UDF.

I'm using AES-256, and Skein hash function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skein_%28hash_function%29). Has anyone successfully implemented an encryption/decryption UDF like that? Is it even possible in Redshift?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to implement any encryption function.  Encryption has been shown to be hard to implement, and even the experts get it wrong.  Would you be able to take a different approach and use some of the built in encryption features that Redshift provides?  For example, I know Redshift provides a whole database encryption to protect the data at rest.

Comment: @BrianCain - thanks for your comment.  I understand that Redshift has hardware encryption of the entire database; however, certain US regulations require certain data to be encrypted on the field/cell level; thus, despite understanding the potential limitations of implementing encryption, I have to do it.